# Getting structure name from the structure address inside the kernel

Tags: linux-device-driver

I have a strange need.

I want to find the structure name passed to the function "dpi_config_lcd_manager(struct omap_dss_device *)" defined at "http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/video/omap2/dss/dpi.c?v=3.8".
I thought of doing in the following way.

```
1. Get the address of the structure.
    A) we can get the structure address within the function.
2. Get the structure name from the address.          
    doubht) Is it possible to get the structure name from the structure address. I think this  structure is defined as static structure, so it will store in the bss section.
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there should be some other design option for you instead of using the structure variable name in the code. Because, once after compilation it becomes just an address. You might want to use a kind of map or key-pair data structure to get the key string mapping to the pointer. Worst case, simply you can have a char array inside the structure.

Comment: Hi,

Could you please tell me or guide me, how to use a kind of map or key-pair data structure to get the key string mapping to the pointer.